# Getting [object Object] as system.out for item.getString() in java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am calling servlet by ajax call and passing multipart form data in POST method.

I retrieve the same data in my servlet and it was working great but then I wanted to send some JSON data with it too.

Here is my JS code in JSP file:

```
var fileSeqMapperMember = {};
        var fileSeqMapperAdvisor = {};
        $(".div_member :input").each(function () {
            var id = this.id
            fileSeqMapperMember[id.substring(13, id.length)] = $(this).val();
        });
        data.append("fileMapperMember", fileSeqMapperMember);
        console.log(fileSeqMapperMember);
        $(".div_advisor :input").each(function () {
            var id = this.id
            fileSeqMapperAdvisor[id.substring(14, id.length)] = $(this).val();
        });
        console.log(fileSeqMapperAdvisor);
        data.append("fileMapperAdvisor", fileSeqMapperAdvisor);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'UploadServlet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //success
                console.log(textStatus);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
            }
        });
```

As you can see I am appending both the JSON to the data object which is declared above as

```
var data = new FormData();
```

On the servlet side I am parsing this data using Commons's libraries.

Here is servlet side code:

```
List items = upload.parseRequest(new ServletRequestContext(req));
        System.out.println(items.size());
        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

            if (!item.isFormField()) {

                itemArray.add(item);
            } else {
                System.out.println(item.getFieldName());
                String currentFieldName = item.getFieldName();

                if (currentFieldName.equals("fileMapperMember")) {
//                      JSONObject memberObj = new JSONObject(item.getString());
//                      System.out.println(memberObj.toString());

                    System.out.println("if member");
                    System.out.println(item.getString());
                } else if (currentFieldName.equals("fileMapperAdvisor")) {
//                      JSONObject advisorObj = new JSONObject(item.getString());
//                      System.out.println(advisorObj.toString());
                        System.out.println("if advisor");
                        System.out.println(item.getString());
                    }else {
                        selectedValue = item.getString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Also below is the log for the same:

```
    3
selection
fileMapperMember
if member
[object Object]
fileMapperAdvisor
if advisor
[object Object]
member
```

I think the object Object is my json data but when I try to parse it as seen in the commented code of servlet, it skips the rest of the code and goes to "finally" and throws Exception.

Sorry for the improper format.

Comment: Java doesn't usually 'crash' -- it will usually throw an Exception which will give you some useful information.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry my mistake.

Comment: Including the Exception stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: All there is in trace is nullpointerexception as the connection object did not get value in an if condition which should become true if above code is executed. Nothing useful there.

Still I will put it for any reason it may help.